# Changing SQL query from one condition to several

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL query which checks for values in a table called ts_allocation to see if the matching rooms that have been "Allocated" (a secondary condition). If they are "Allocated" then it does not return them in the result. Unfortunately due to design constraints, I can't have this condition in my table anymore.

I now want to change it so that it sees if the rooms have a value either than "Pending", "Failed" or "Declined". If it is any of the three then the result will be returned and not ignored (unlike before).

Once the rooms have been acquired in the first where clause the system needs to check whether they are "Pending", "Failed" or "Declined" in the ts_allocation table. A room can be booked for a certain day or period - but if its status remains "Pending", "Failed" or "Declined" then it is viewed. Anything else would imply the room is booked.

I hope I'm making sense here... here's my code so far:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) totalCount 
FROM 
  ts_room rm
WHERE building_id=:building_id AND  
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM ts_roompref rp
      JOIN ts_request rq
      ON rp.request_id = rq.id
      AND day_id = 4
      AND period_id = ".$i."
    WHERE 
      rm.id = rp.room_id)
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM ts_roompref rp
      JOIN ts_allocation a
      ON rp.request_id = a.request_id
      AND a.status = 'Allocated'
    WHERE 
      rm.id = rp.room_id)
```

Comment: provide at least the key column lists for the `ts_room`, `ts_roompref` and `ts_allocation` tables

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1021/6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the room key back as the result of the query...

```
SELECT DISTINCT rm.Id as RoomId
FROM ts_room rm LEFT JOIN ts_roompref rp ON rp.room_id = rm.id
  LEFT JOIN ts_request rq ON rq.id = rp.request_id
  LEFT JOIN ts_allocation a ON a.request_id = rq.id
WHERE building_id = :building_id
  AND (a.status IS NULL OR a.status IN ('Pending', 'Failed', 'Declined'))
```