# SQL query omitting certain values

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to return all rooms that do not exist in the **ts_allocation** table (i.e. have not been allocated) or have Pending, Failed or Declined status in the **ts_allocation** table. The rooms can meet one of thouse clauses.

But several values such as D.0.02 are being omitted (please refer to fiddle)? Why is this? It exists in the **ts_allocation** with the above-mentioned status - but it does not seem to fulfil a certain clause. How can I resolve this?

Here is my SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1021/6

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  ts_room rm
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM ts_roompref rp
      JOIN ts_request rq
      ON rp.request_id = rq.id
      AND day_id = 1
      AND period_id = 1
    WHERE 
      rm.id = rp.room_id)
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM ts_roompref rp
      JOIN ts_allocation a
      ON rp.request_id = a.request_id
            AND a.status <> 'Pending'
            AND a.status <> 'Failed'
            AND a.status <> 'Declined'
    WHERE 
      rm.id = rp.room_id)
```

Comment: Please simplify your problem to the relevant parts and post those details not only in the fiddle.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947940/changing-sql-query-from-one-condition-to-several/14948960#14948960, do not post the same query multiple times

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  rm.* 
FROM    ts_room rm
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT  a.*, rp.room_id 
            FROM    ts_roompref rp 
                    INNER JOIN  dbo.ts_allocation a on a.request_id = rp.request_id) x 
                    ON  x.room_id = rm.id
WHERE   x.id is null    
        or (x.id is not null and x.status in ('Pending', 'Failed','Declined'))
```

`x.id is null` gives you all rooms that have not been allocated and the `or` part gives you **more results** - those rooms that have either Pending, Declined or Failed status.